# Java string split without space

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to split some user input. The input is of the form a1 b2 c3 d4.
For each input (eg; a1), how do I split it into 'a' and '1'?

I'm familiar with the string split function, but what do I specify as the delimiter or is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split the string generically (rather than trying to count characters per the other answers), you can still use String.split(), but you have to utilize [regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum). (Note: This answer will work when you have strings like a1, a2, aaa333, etc.)

```
String ALPHA = "\p{Alpha}";
String NUMERIC = "\d";

String test1 = "a1";
String test2 = "aa22";

ArrayList<String> alpha = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> numeric = new ArrayList();

alpha.add(test1.split(ALPHA));
numeric.add(test1.split(NUMERIC));
alpha.add(test2.split(ALPHA));
numeric.add(test2.split(NUMERIC));
```

At this point, the alpha array will have the alpha parts of your strings and the numeric array will have the numeric parts. (Note: I didn't actually compile this to test that it would work, but it should give you the basic idea.)

Comment: "\p{Alpha}" gives me an error saying "Invalid escape sequence".

Comment: @Triple777er - Try "[a-zA-Z]" for now instead of "\p{Alpha}".

Comment: Thanks a lot Jas, I got a basic idea on how to do it now.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [String#substring()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
String a1 = "a1"
String firstLetterStr = a1.substring(0,1);
String secondLetterStr = a1.substirng(1,a1.length());
```

Similarly,

```
String c31 = "c31"
String firstLetterStr = c31.substring(0,1);
String secondLetterStr = c31.substirng(1,c31.length());
```

Comment: Won't work if he chooses 'aa31' or something of the like. Don't know if it's possible, but, just figured I would point it out.

Comment: @JasCav: Of course this wouldn't. But let the OP comes and say something like this. I already made a mistake of editing the original question based on a similar comment -- not from OP.

Comment: @Adeel - Good point. Sometimes it is actually better to go with the simple answer based on the needs of the developer. I do have to be careful not to overengineer solutions at times.

Answer (score 2):

it really depends how you're going to use the data afterwards, but besides `split("")` or accessing individual characters by index, one other way to split into individual character is `toCharArray()` -- which just breaks the string into an array of characters...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you can use `split("");`

Answer (score 1):

After you split user input into individual tokens using `split(" ")`, you can split each token into characters using `split("")` (using the empty string as the delimiter).

Answer (score 0):

Split on space into an array of Strings, then pull the individual characters with `String.charAt(0)` and `String.charAt(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just iterating over the characters in threes.

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 3) {
     char theLetter = str.charAt(i);
     char theNumber = str.charAt(i + 1);
     // Do something
}
```

Edit: if it can be more than one letter or digit, use regular expressions:

```
([a-z]+)(\d+)
```

Information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: I figured it was 1 letter/1 digit combinations. It could be, still.

Comment: Thanks. It's only for 1 letter 1 digit combination.